# Get product in stock proucts when manage stock enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, php, stock, manage-stock

I'm doing some customization on magento 1.9.x website. I need to get all products with **in stock** and manage **stock enabled**

I'm using this code

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1);

    $productIds = array();

    foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
        $productIds[] = $item->getOrigData('product_id');
    }

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=> $productIds));
    $productCollection->load();


    $i=0;
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
        $i++;
        echo $i.'-'.$_product->getId().'<br/>';
    }
```

But the problem is this list shows the items which not **enable manage stock** like this

[image]

I only need to get products which **manage stock** enabled and **in stock**

like below

[image]

Anyone know how to get that with my code or using another code, Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the manage inventory column to the collection, try this:

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('manage_stock', 1)

$productIds = []];

foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
    $productIds[] = $item->getOrigData('product_id');
}

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in'=> $productIds])
    ->load();


$i=0;

foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
    $i++;
    echo $i.'-'.$_product->getId().'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an OR condition in the code inorder to check the `use_config_manage_stock`

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter(
    array('manage_stock', 'use_config_manage_stock'),
    array(
        array('eq'=>'1'), 
        array('eq'=>'1')
    )
);

$productIds = [];

foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
}

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in'=> $productIds])
    ->load();

$i = 0;
foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
    $i++;
    echo $i.'-'.$_product->getId().'<br/>';
}
```